# Как сделать чтобы цвета менялись без остановки, то есть продолжали меняться при закрытой странице?

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:0px">
  <div id="cvet1"></div>
  <div id="cvet2"></div>
  <div id="cvet3"></div>
  <div id="cvet4"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  border: 0px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function zapusk(d) {
  if (!d.rgb) {
    d.rgb = 0;
  }

  s = (d.rgb).toString(16);
  while (s.length < 3) {
    s = '0' + s;
  }
  s = '#' + s;
  d.style.backgroundColor = s;
  //document.getElementById("log").innerHTML=s;

  d.rgb+= 1;
  if (d.rgb > 0xfff) d.rgb = 0;
}

window.onload=function(){
  setInterval(function(){ zapusk(document.getElementById('cvet1'))}, 1);
  setInterval(function(){ zapusk(document.getElementById('cvet2'))}, 2);
  setInterval(function(){ zapusk(document.getElementById('cvet3'))}, 3);
  setInterval(function(){ zapusk(document.getElementById('cvet4'))}, 4);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите вопрос ещё раз. Так очень трудно читать.

Comment: «при закрытой странице» — т.е. когда даже чел браузер закрыл? Сделайте цвет зависимым от абсолютного времени, например.

p.s. Перевёл ваш аццкий код в читаемый [фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/3sPGu/).

Comment: можно привести пример html кода

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно запоминать последнее состояние - используйте cookie или local storage